# Model MVC IEnumerable without Iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Rookie Question. So I have a IEnumerable Model And as you can see my question is simple. I just want to get the Value of the First item in the model Without iterating through the whole model.

As this is only one instance to happen. I don't want to itterate from the model just to get 1 Entity from it and I wouldn't also want to rely on the ViewBag or ViewData for this.

Is this possible?

`Client = Model.FirstOrDefault().ClientID`

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I also tried `select()`

```
@model IEnumerable<RMQGrainsFinalCement.ModelsCorn.POCorn>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "POIndex";
}

<h2>PO Index</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Add PO", "Create", "POCorns", new {ClientID =   Model.FirstOrDefault().ClientID },null)
```

Comment: So you've told us you've tried using `FirstOrDefault()`, but you haven't told us what *happened*.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will stop after the first element, so you are not iterating through the whole thing.

Comment: You will get a null reference exception if there is not data.  Safer to use `Model.First().ClientID` which will still throw if there is no data but it is built to do so and made to catch.

Comment: Model is empty or Model is null

Comment: Got it to work thanks, Claudio, I just wanted to confirm If I am doing the syntax correctly. So I added some code in the controller to add an object to the list if there is no result from the context.

Comment: Since you are adding a default value if none exist, use `.First()` instead of `.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mitigate unexpected errors, do something like this in your view:

```
@{
    var clientId = 0;
    if (Model.Any())
    {
        clientId = Model.First().ClientId;
    }
 }
 @Html.ActionLink("Add PO", "Create", "POCorns", new {ClientID = clientID },null)
```

Comment: I added a blank object in my Controller. I will try this now.

Comment: Thanks, I will just control the ClientID 0 in the Create Controller :D